# cmake isn't adding all the files of a project to the compile_commands.json database

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

I'm running cmake version 3.8.1

I've added `set( CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON )` to my main CMakeLists.txt so that it created the `compile_commands.json` database.

For some unknown reason headers that are in a list like this:

```
set(INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 
    "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.15/Engine/Source"
...
)
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
```

are missing in that JSON file. Is there any good reason for such behavior?

Comment: Because sources are .c / .cc /.cpp files. Headers are not considered sources which the user has to add.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought I might be using the compile_commands.json to extract headers information